# Move a section from one config file to another with configparser

Tags: python-2.7, file, python-2.x, configparser

I have two files:

test1.conf:

```
[1414]
musicclass = cowo1108
eventwhencalled = yes
eventmemberstatus = yes
membermacro = AnswerNotifyOngoingEntered
strategy = ringall
timeout = 35
```

test2.conf:

```
[1415]
musicclass = cowo1108
eventwhencalled = yes
eventmemberstatus = yes
membermacro = AnswerNotifyOngoingEntered
strategy = ringall
timeout = 35
```

I just want to put the section [1414] from test1.conf under the section from test2.conf, and then delete from test1.conf

I tried converting the section into a dictionary and then adding it to the test2, but it didn't include the section name, just the configs, and I need all the configs to move (section name and it's configs).

I just need something to work with, then I'll see what I can do to insert it in my code. I have read the documentation of course, but I couldn't find anything that paste a full section.

Here is what I tried (the file is large so I got pieces of it):

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(strict=False,comment_prefixes='/',allow_no_value=True)
with open('test1.conf', "r") as f:
    config.readfp(f)

for general_queue_id in config.sections():
    general_id_arr.append(general_queue_id)

for key in general_id_arr: # Array with all sections from test1.conf
    with open('teste2.conf'):
        items = {k:v for k,v in config.items(key)}
        for x in items.items():
            f.write(x[0] + '=' + x[1] + '\n')
```

Comment: What code have _you_ written to try to make this work?

Comment: @ForceBru I Have edited my question with the code. Just to justify, the test1.conf will have many sections.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the section that you are looking for it will be easier to use the builtin functions found in configParser that you can build into a wrapper class.

For example, I use the following to create my parser and then grab all of the items in a section as a list.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser, ExtendedInterpolation


class MyConfigParser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        initialize the file parser with
        ExtendedInterpolation to use ${Section:variable} format
        [Section]
        option=variable
        """
        self.config_parser = ConfigParser(interpolation=ExtendedInterpolation())

    def read_ini_file(self, file):
        """
        Parses in the passed in INI file.

        :param file: INI file to parse
        :return: INI file is parsed
        """
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            self.config_parser.read_file(f)

    def add_section_toFile(self, section):
        """
        adds a configuration section to a file

        :param section: configuration section to add in file
        :return: void
        """
        if not self.config_parser.has_section(section):
            self.config_parser.add_section(section)

    def add_configurations_to_section(self, section, lst_config):
        """
        Adds a configuration list to configuration section

        :param section: configuration section
        :param lst_config: key, value list of configurations
        :return: void
        """
        if not self.config_parser.has_section(section):
            self.add_section_toFile(section)

        for option, value in lst_config:
            print(option, value)
            self.config_parser.set(section, option, value)


    def get_config_items_by_section(self, section):
        """
        Retrieves the configurations for a particular section

        :param section: INI file section
        :return: a list of name, value pairs for the options in the section
        """
        return self.config_parser.items(section)

    def remove_config_section(self, section):
        """
        Removes a configuration section from a file
        :param section: configuration section to remove
        :return: void
        """
        self.config_parser.remove_section(section)

    def remove_options_from_section(self, section, lst_options):
        """
        Removes a list of options from configuration section
        :param section: configuration section in file
        :param lst_options: list of options to remove
        :return: void
        """
        for option, value in lst_options:
            self.config_parser.remove_option(section, option)

    def write_file(self, file, delimiter=True):
        with open(file, 'w') as f:
            self.config_parser.write(f, delimiter)
```

I added functions that wrap functions from the configParser api that will help accomplish what you are attempting found in these api sections [add_section & set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.add_section) along with [remove_section & remove_option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.remove_section)

To use it you can create your instance and call it with something such as:

```
from config_parser import MyConfigParser


def main():
    lst_section = []

    fileIn = './test1.conf'
    fileOut = './test2.conf'

    parser1 = MyConfigParser()
    parser2 = MyConfigParser()

    parser1.read_ini_file(fileIn)
    parser2.read_ini_file(fileOut)

    lst_section = parser1.get_config_items_by_section('1414')

    parser2.add_section_toFile('1414')
    parser2.add_configurations_to_section('1414', lst_section)

    parser1.remove_config_section('1414')

    parser1.write_file(fileIn)
    parser2.write_file(fileOut)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The MyConfigParser class was a quick build, so if you are going to use it in a production type environment, you will want to add in more robust error handling to catch things like if the section option already exist. The configParser api will typically show what error will occur that you can but try/except to handle that exception type. Unless I made a mistake in the copy paste, i ended up putting together something that I was able to test that it ran for you. I hope this helps.